# What is difference between JsonResponse and HttpResponse in django

Tags: python, django

Lets say `result = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`

Is there a difference between these two:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(a))
```

and

```
return JsonResponse(a)
```

Answer (score 8):

As [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) states, main difference is

- automatic serialization
- proper content type
- safer input check by default

Answer (score 4):

Django uses request and response objects to pass state through the system. Each view is responsible for returning an HttpResponse object. Using HttpResponse you need to first serialize your object to JSON.

Whereas,

Since version 1.7, Django counts with the built-in `JsonResponse` class, which is a subclass of `HttpResponse`. Its default Content-Type header is set to application/json, which is really convenient. It also comes with a JSON encoder, so you don’t need to serialize the data before returning the response object.

You can also refer [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/27/how-to-return-json-encoded-response.html) doc:

Answer (score 3):

Try this it will pass

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps("abcd"))
```

But if  you do

```
return JsonResponse("abcd")
```

`JsonResponse` will give you `TypeError` if you send non serializable data (Unless `safe=False` in JsonResponse)

So it is safer to send json data in `JsonResponse`

And in header `JsonResponse` will set `Content-Type: application/json` on the other hand `HttpResponse` will set `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

- **HTTPResponse**

  - HTTPResponse (content=response body, content_type=response body data type, status=status code)
  - Suitable for string, templates
  - `class HttpResponse(HttpResponseBase):`
- **JsonReponse**

  - It is a subclass of HTTPResponse,

    - Suitable for processing data in json format, but can not return templates.
    - `class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):`

Refer [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse)